# "No matching records found" when using bootstrap-table in Flask

Tags: python, html, json, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I'm now developing website based on flask, and I want to load a data.json using bootstrap-table. But I only got the table without the data.

The directory structure displays as below:

```
index.py
templates/
    new.html
    data.json
    data1.json
static/
    css/
        bootstrap-table.css
        bootstrap-theme.css     
        bootstrap-theme.min.css 
        bootstrap.css.map
        base.css               
        bootstrap-table.min.css 
        bootstrap-theme.css.map 
        bootstrap.css          
        bootstrap.min.css
    js/
        bootstrap-table.js     
        bootstrap.js           
        bower_components/     
        jquery.min.js
        bootstrap-table.min.js 
        bootstrap.min.js       
        index.js               
        npm.js
```

and the index.py looks like this:

```
62 @app.route("/")
63 def new():
64     return render_template('new.html')
```

the 'new .html' looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Config{% endblock %}
{% block head %}
{{ super() }}
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src='../static/js/index.js'></script> -->
{% endblock %}
{% block header %}
    <p class="title">test</p>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<table data-toggle="table" data-url="data1.json" data-cache="false" data-height="299">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="id">Item ID</th>
        <th data-field="name">Item Name</th>
        <th data-field="price">Item Price</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

and I've link all the css and js files needed in the base.html

But when the index.py is running, I got the page as below. It only displays table, but without data

[image]

Does anyone have met this problem?

Comment: Can you show us the code you use to load the data?

Comment: @dazedconfused According to the example on [bootstrap-table](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/examples.html),I think the data can be loaded when setting the 'data-url=data1.json' in the html. Is it incorrect?

Comment: It seems to be correct; what does your `data1.json` look like? Does it contains `id`, `name` and `price` as its fields? Also, I found you didn't include `jquery`, `bootstrap` and `bootstrap-table` in your `new.html`; see [Usage](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/getting-started.html#usage)

Comment: @dazedconfused  data1.json is the same as the [example on official website](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/data1.json), and I have link all the files in the base.html. As the tables shows, the css is working no problem, but only the data is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in terms of Flask, make sure the json file is located in the static folder. It's so trivial that I have tried many times to figure it out.

Then, make sure the format of your json file which contains a json array is correct.

FYR
[Bootstrap table showing JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187349/bootstrap-table-showing-json-data)