# bootstrap table unable to load json objects

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

My ajax script sends json objects to browser but the table is unable to load the json object.
My Ajax script:

```
 $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "getLabels.jsp",
            data : "mailingID=" + selectedValue, // posCodeSelected
            success : function(data) {

                response = $.parseJSON(data);// this statement sends data succesfully to browser

            },
            error : function(response) {
                var responseTextObject = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
            }
        });
```

This is my bootstrap table embedded into my jsp page.

```
<table data-height="299" data-show-refresh="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-search="true" data-select-item-name="toolbar1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="rowNumber" >ID</th>
        <th data-field="firstname" >first name</th>
        <th data-field="lastname" >last name</th>
        <th data-field="organization" >organization</th>
        <th data-field="city" >city</th>
        <th data-field="state" >state</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Just to let you guys now this is my json response in browser:

```
{"rowNumber":1,"mailingID":3,"firstname":"Brian","lastname":"Fairhurst","organization":"Florida State University","city":"Tallahassee","state":"FL"}
```

Comment: What are you doing with `response` after you parse the JSON?

Comment: This post might help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187349/bootstrap-table-showing-json-data

Comment: @BlaiseSwanwick: yes, the link you have provided has table attribute data-url="test.json" which loads the json file. But in my case I have to load the json objects(response) into table.

Comment: I'll make an answer then. glad that helped.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a new row with the json object returned:

```
//you need to set id="tbl" to your table on the html

var table = document.getElementById("tbl"); 

var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length); //insert a new row

// insert new cells with info

cells = [];

for(var i = 0;i < 6;i++){
    cells[i] = row.insertCell(i);
}

// add the information store in json object

cells[0].innerHTML = response.rowNumber;
cells[0].innerHTML = response.firstname;
cells[0].innerHTML = response.lastname;
cells[0].innerHTML = response.organization;
cells[0].innerHTML = response.city;
cells[0].innerHTML = response.state;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the HTML table isn't being populated with the data in `response`.  Adding the `data-url` attribute to your HTML table should work.

So, instead of:

```
<table data-height="299" data-show-refresh="true" ...>
    <thead>
    ...
```

You'll want to do:

```
<table data-height="299" data-show-refresh="true" data-url="response"...>
    <thead>
    ...
```